# JBoss não está iniciando

Tags: jboss, demoiselle

Estou com o problema abaixo no JBoss, e gostaria de saber o que devo fazer, pois não está iniciando.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O consegui mudar o problema ..Agora exibe este erro agora  ---       
08:30:11,609 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"DenunciasFinal.war#denuncias-ds\"jboss.naming.context.java.denunciasdsMissing[jboss.persistenceunit.\"DenunciasFinal.war#denuncias-ds\"jboss.naming.context.java.denunciasds]"]}}}

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se o persistence.xml foi empacotado no seu war e se no arquivo existe uma persistence-unit com o nome "denuncias-ds".